# In CSS , visited link does not change color

Tags: html, css

I am newbie  learning web development.
Following is my `test.html` file and `test.css` files in the snippet below.

Now, I have latest Mozilla firefox (66.0.5) and Chrome (74.0.3729.131) browsers. I have the setting in firefox to never remember history. But Chrome has setting to remember history.  When I open `test.html`, the link color appears red in Firefox and blue in Chrome. Clicking on the link does not alter the colors in these browsers. So what is the cause of this behavior and how do I make the link turn blue only after its clicked ?

```css
 /* give red color to web link  */

 a {
   color: red ;
 }

 /* give blue color to the link after its
 visited */

 a:visited {
   color: blue ;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google !</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using a:focus

Comment: @Rachel, Thanks. Its much better than `a:visited`. How do I choose your answer here since its just a comment ?

Comment: I'll add it (if you insist ;) )

Comment: @Rachel, please do :) Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `a:visited`, use [a:focus`.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

It's proven more reliable for me as the color changes when the link receives focus, visited seems unreliable as cached visits  affect it ..boo

Hope this helps